# Oracle Database PLSQL Error: PLS-00103

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm writing simple function in Oracle Database 11g that count summary salary for employee. For this we need to count days with specific status. Days is present as fields in table (Day_1, Day_2, ..., Day_30).
But i have got error during compilation:
`Error(50,9): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: :=.(@%;`
Code of my package (a place where there is an error marked in code of function `f2`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pack IS
    FUNCTION f1 (id IN NUMBER) return t2 PIPELINED;
    FUNCTION f2 (id IN NUMBER) return number;
end pack;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack IS

FUNCTION f1 (id IN NUMBER) return t2 PIPELINED IS

  name      VARCHAR2(50);
  num       number;

BEGIN

  FOR i IN 1 .. id LOOP

    SELECT отдел
      into name
      from отдел
      where ид_отдела = i;

    select sum(КОЛИЧЕСТВО)
      into num
      from Таблица_3
      join Таблица_2
      on Таблица_3.КТО_ПРОДАЛ = Таблица_2.ЧЛВК_ИД
      where отдел = i;

    PIPE ROW( t1(i, name, num) );

  END LOOP;

  RETURN;

END f1;

FUNCTION f2 (id IN NUMBER) return NUMBER AS

  WorkingDays     NUMBER := 0;
  CurrentDay    VARCHAR2(50);
  Salary        NUMBER := 120;
  Total           NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN

  FOR i IN 1 .. 30 LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT День_' || i || ' FROM Таблица_2 WHERE ЧЛВК_ИД = id INTO CurrentDay';

    IF WorkingDays IN ('КОМАНДИРОВКА','ВЫХОДНОЙ','ПРАЗДНИК') THEN -- <--- Here
      WorkingDays := WorkingDays + 1;
    END IF;

  END LOOP;
  Total : = Salary * WorkingDays;

  RETURN Total;

END f2;

end pack;
/
```

How can i solve this? Maybe the problem is in the logic of the program?

Comment: The syntax for executing dynamic SQL, assuming you want your predicate to use the parameter to `f2` would be `execute immediate `select statement` into CurrentDay using id`

Comment: I can't see where `ДНИ` variable is declared. There is also more problems - `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT День_' || i || ' FROM Таблица_2 WHERE ЧЛВК_ИД = id INTO CurrentDay';` will fail, since  `currentDay` is not known in this context --> execute immediate doesn't see variables delared in the context of calling procedure.

Comment: @kordirko i'm sorry, `ДНИ` now called `WorkingDays`, i forgot to change this. So if CurrentDay is out of sub-query context, how can i solve my problem with iterating nth fields of my table in 1 row? And what's mean Error PLS-00103 in my case?

Comment: Total : = Salary * WorkingDays; That space between the colon and equal sign may be breaking the parser. Usually that error is a syntax error somewhere in the vicinity of the indicated line, but not always right on that line.

Answer (score 1):

That is an error on parsing, and be aware that it often does not accurately show the error itself, but where the next symbol error occurred. For example:

```
declare
  x number;
  y number;
begin
 if x = 1 then
   y := 1     --I forget to put on the semi-colon to end the line
 end if;
end;
```

You'd expect an error on the missing semi-colon. What you get is:

```
ORA-06550: line 7, column 2:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.
```

Since in your comments you talk about changing things - perhaps to make it more readable for us (and thank you!), it may be obscuring the actual syntax glitch.

Two things I notice:

Total : = Salary * WorkingDays;

That has a space between the : and = that shouldn't be there

and:

```
FUNCTION f2 (id IN NUMBER) return NUMBER AS
```

which is normally

```
 FUNCTION f2 (id IN NUMBER) return NUMBER IS
```

Comment: `is` and `as` are interchangeable in this context. See railroad diagram for function definition http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/function.htm#LNPLS1182